# Map a namespaced getter (maintaining reactivity) in Vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuex-modules

I know you can use a standard getter from your Vuex store by importing mapGetters...

```
import {mapGetters} from 'vuex';
```

Then adding a computed property as follows:

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
        myGetter: 'my-getter'
    })
}
```

I have split my Vuex store into modules in order to use namespaced actions/mutations.

I want to use 'mapGetters' in order to access a getter from a specific module.

---

TL;DR - What would be the necessary changes in syntax for mapping a modular namespaced getter in Vuex from the above snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the syntax to be used:

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters('moduleOne', ['getUsers']),
    ...mapGetters('moduleTwo', ['getProducts'])
},
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the way. There is an extra apostrophe in the getUsers line which I had to remove in practice to match the syntax of the getProducts line

Comment: I see that issue is resolved and the sytax now works perfectly. +1 @Pradipta